# How to calculate how many times a specific substring appears in a database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2007

My Access database data looks like:

```
srno       likes
user 1     001,002,003
user 2     001,004,005,007
user 2     001,007,009,001
etc
```

I want to calculate how many times each individual value in the `likes` column, i.e. `001`, `002`, etc, appears in the table.

I used this code:

```
 cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\Acetech.mdb"))
        cnn.Open()
        msg = "SELECT COUNT(001) FROM (productfeedback) WHERE three like '001' OR second like '001' "

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(msg, cnn)
        str = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        cnn.Close()
```

It should display `001 4`:

```
    If str Is DBNull.Value Then
        Label12.Text = "0"
    Else
        Label12.Text = Format(CStr(TextBox2.Text)) & Convert.ToInt32(str)
    End If
```

Comment: how the likes are stored in the database??, as a string?

Comment: like is in string format

Comment: you can write a query to get all the likes first from the Likes Column, and then you can do a count based on the value you get

Comment: why don't you fetch all the record for database and then in your code split individual row on comma and then count it.

Comment: @shekhar i am doing the way u said but i am not able to count..

Comment: put you code in your question.

Comment: Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

               cnn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\Acetech.mdb"))
        cnn.Open()
        msg = "SELECT COUNT(first) FROM (productfeedback) WHERE First ='001' OR Second='001' OR Fourth ='001' Or fifth ='001' OR three='001'"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(msg, cnn)
        str = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        cnn.Close()


        If str Is DBNull.Value Then
            Label12.Text = "0"
        Else
            Label12.Text = Format(CStr(TextBox2.Text)) & Convert.ToInt32(str)

        End If

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve it in code and not by sql. I tried VB.NET but this is not my first language and I used a test Datatable

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()

dt.Columns.Add("srno", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("likes", GetType(String))

dt.Rows.Add("User 1", "001,002,003")
dt.Rows.Add("User 2", "001,004,005,007")
dt.Rows.Add("User 3", "001,007,009,001")

Dim q = From l In dt.AsEnumerable() _
            Select l

Dim likes As New List(Of String)()
For Each row In q
    likes.AddRange(row("likes").Split(","))
Next

Dim likesGroupedBy = likes.GroupBy(Function(item) item).[Select](Function(group) New With { _
 group.Key, _
 Key .Count = group.Count() _
})

Dim ret As String = String.Empty
For Each row In likesGroupedBy
    ret += String.Format("key:{0}, count:{1}" + Environment.NewLine, row.Key, row.Count)
Next
```